# Не могу установить homebrew на centos

Tags: linux, centos, homebrew

При попытке установки получаю следующее сообщение. Не могу понять что от меня требуется. Устанавливаю на облачном хостинге.

```
[root@server root]# sudo /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Found Git: /bin/git
==> Found cURL: /bin/curl
==> Setting HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER to use Git/cURL not in /usr/bin
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Don't run this as root!
[root@server root]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запуск нужно делать не от пользователя root, чтобы выполнить команду под рутом от имени другого пользователя есть команда:

```
sudo -H -u username bash -c 'your command'
```

В моем случае итоговая команда для установки выглядит так:

```
sudo -H -u www-root bash -c '/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"'
```

Answer (score 1):

написано что вы запускаете от рута то, что не надо, попробуйте от обычного юзера запустить

Comment: доступ по ssh есть только у root пользователя =(